# Using GitLens in VSCode, how do I selectively reintroduce stashed changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

I'm using VSCode, I tried some changes that break the app.
I stashed the changes and the app works OK. Now I want to reintroduce the changes one by one to get to the problem.

When I open the stash in GitLens and select `Open changes with working file`, I can see the two versions side by side, but I can only move changes from the working file to the stash; I can't pick out changes from the stash into the working file. How am I supposed to proceed to gently merge in a stash?

And another thing: in the header of the comparison, I see commit numbers, not human-readable descriptions such as `Working file` or `Stash: <my stash name>`. Is there a way of getting something similar?